# Convert datetime to yyyy-mm-dd:hh in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert `yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-mm-dd:hh` in SQL Server?

I want to convert `2013-04-30:10:34:23` to `2013-04-30:10:00:00`?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read [`this`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp), this will help you how to convert or short any date format in SQL sever

Example

The following script uses the CONVERT() function to display different formats. We will use the GETDATE() function to get the current date/time:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

The result would look something like this:

```
Nov 04 2011 11:45 PM
11-04-11
11-04-2011
04 Nov 11
04 Nov 2011
04 Nov 2011 11:45:34:243
```

Answer (score 3):

can you tried this

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), GETDATE(), 120), ' ', ':')
```

for more help please refer this [link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If both input and result are in `datetime` format, you could just use [`substring`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to get the desired output.